# How to dynamically change HTML input name

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm creating a small shopping cart project where I get a list of products in a linked list from a servlet. Now, I am printing the values of the linkedlist in a table with an option for users to select the quantities they want.
Which ever has quantity selected should go on to the next page as an attribute

> Here are few issues I am facing:
>
> 1: Since the list has more than 1 items, each item listed should have
>   input field. How to I dynamically change the input name for the
>   quantity which I can later use as an attribute.
>
> 2: The available quantity of items vary from product to product, how
>   to I set the max value of the quantity to the available stock.
>
> 3: If I can manage to get the values, how do I set all the attributes.
>   Is it in the for loop or outside the for loop?

Here is the code for the reference.[Picture of what the page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DLyu.png)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%-- <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> --%>
<%@page import="shoppingcart.model.items.*,java.util.*" %>

<%List<ItemDetailsPojo> listp = (List<ItemDetailsPojo>) session.getAttribute("ItemsData");

    %>
    <%-- <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> --%>
    <Center>
        <h3 style="color: blue">Welcome To the World of Shopping</h3>
    </Center>
    <div align='right'>Logged in as:</div>

 <div align="center">
        <table border="10" cellpadding="5">
            <caption>
                <h2>List of Items</h2>
            </caption>
            <tr>
                <th>ItemId</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Available</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>
            <%for(int i=0;i<listp.size();i++){%>
                <tr>
                    <td><%out.println(listp.get(i).getItemId());%></td>
                    <td><%out.println(listp.get(i).getItemName());%></td>
                    <td><%out.println(listp.get(i).getCategory());%></td>
                    <td><%out.println(listp.get(i).getPrice());%></td>
                    <td><%out.println(listp.get(i).getQuantity());%></td>
                    <% int number = listp.get(i).getQuantity(); %>
                    <td><input type="number" name="should dynamically change according to the size of the list" min="0" max="should change according the the quantity  available"></td>
                </tr>
            <%} %>
        </table>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<td><input type="number" name="quantity<%=i%>" min="0" max="<%=listp.get(i).getQuantity()%>"></td>
```

**and you need to set all the attributes outside the loop.**

Comment: Worked like a charm,Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Edit your code like this**

```
<%List<ItemDetailsPojo> listp = (List<ItemDetailsPojo>) session.getAttribute("ItemsData");

            %>
            <%-- <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> --%>
            <Center>
                <h3 style="color: blue">Welcome To the World of Shopping</h3>
            </Center>
            <div align='right'>Logged in as:</div>

         <div align="center">
                <table border="10" cellpadding="5">
                    <caption>
                        <h2>List of Items</h2>
                    </caption>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ItemId</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Available</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                    <%
     String name;
    for(int i=0;i<listp.size();i++){%>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%out.println(listp.get(i).getItemId());%></td>
                            <td><%out.println(listp.get(i).getItemName());%></td>
                            <td><%out.println(listp.get(i).getCategory());%></td>
                            <td><%out.println(listp.get(i).getPrice());%></td>
                            <td><%out.println(listp.get(i).getQuantity());%></td>
                            <% int number = listp.get(i).getQuantity();
    name="quantity".concat(listp.get(i).getQuantity());
     %>
                            <td><input type="number"name="<%=name%>" min="0" max="should change according the the quantity  available"></td>
                        </tr>
                    <%} %>
                </table>

            </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```